# New (2.6) $cond Aggregation Framework with c#?

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

I'm going crazy with this one...

I have this aggregation framework expression working like a charm in mongo shell:

```
{ $group : 
    {
    _id : '$Code' , 
    'Special' : { $sum : { $cond: [{ $eq: [ '$Special', 'Success']},1,0]}}
    }
}
```

I need to do it in c#, I tried a lot of combinations but without success.

Has anyone any clue?

Thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
var group = new BsonDocument
{
    {
        "$group",
        new BsonDocument
        {
            {
                "_id", "$Code"
            },
            {
                "Special", new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "$sum", new BsonDocument
                        {
                            {"$cond", new BsonArray
                                {
                                    new BsonDocument
                                    {
                                        {
                                            "$eq", new BsonArray {"$Special", "Success"}
                                        }
                                    },
                                    1,
                                    0
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! You did it! BTW C# driver for aggregation is so complex and verbose! If it could get standard javascript format in input it could really help.

Comment: Agreed. The aggregation code you end up writing looks hideous. There's no way other developers are going to be able to figure out what is going on at a glance.